# Autorefreshing a tool/web page

Tags: javascript, executable, exe

I have a tool/software which is web-based. It will have entries. To get to know the current status we need to click over "refresh" button in the tool. It's very difficult to click the button frequently.

So I thought of have an exe file which will run and refresh the above said tool automatically, so it will overcome the difficulty in refreshing the tool manually.

can you please help in out in doing this? Can this be done using javascript?

Comment: Please explain your problem better. How is JavaScript related to creating an exe-file? If you just want to refresh the page with JavaScript, this is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293160/how-do-i-refresh-the-browser-every-x-seconds-with-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a browser plugins to refresh page every 5 mins.

["Reload Every" for Firefox, for example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/)