# modify page reload interval after first page auto reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to modify the page refresh time after the first page reload (which is 30s) then reload the page after every 5min if user is still on page. At the moment it reloads forever every 30 seconds.

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

window.onload = timedRefresh(30000);
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293160/how-do-i-refresh-the-browser-every-x-seconds-with-javascript

Comment: You could set a localStorage value to see if they have set the initial timer, then if so, change it to 5 minutes. Though on a contextual scale, this seems rather annoying for a website. Why not refresh what you need with ajax?

Comment: You can not do this with a reload because the same script would just start all over again. You might want to redirect the user with a URL query parameter and if that parameter exists, you change the time

Comment: @Microsmsm not a duplicate, question is asking how to change the time after the first refresh

Answer (score 0):

You could set a parameter in your URL which tells you whether it is the first page reload or not, something like `http://www.yoururl.com?fr=1`, where `fr` stands for "first reload".

After that, you just need to get that querystring parameter the best way it suits you, either via JavaScript or capturing its value at the server side and then sending it to the client.

Finally, you just need to check the condition to decide whether to reload after 30 seconds of 5 minutes.

For example, supposing you have the value of `fr`in a variable named `firstReload`:

```
window.onload = timedRefresh(firstReload == "1" ? 30000 : 300000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save in localStorage number of reloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save flag that page was loaded first time

```
var timeout = localStorage.getItem('pageloaded') ? 3e5 : 3e4;
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
   localStorage.setItem('pageloaded', true);
   setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

window.onload = timedRefresh(timeout);
```

Comment: unfortunately it keeps refreshing

Comment: Where can I set the refresh time here?

Comment: 3e5 and 3e4 are refresh times.
3e5 = 300000; 3e4  = 30000;

Comment: It should refreshe after 30 seconds first time and after 5 minutes second, third ... time. Isn't it?

Comment: i have modified that in the fiddle to 5s and then 1s https://jsfiddle.net/rnpqas21/

Comment: I can't get exactly what behavior you need? I thought it was exactly flow that you need.

Comment: stop after first refresh time 30s then refresh page at every 5min. but to speed up how the code works, I have changed the times to 5s and 1s in the fiddle code

Comment: it looks like it works that way but you already have in localstorage pageloaded of true.

Answer (score 0):

By using localStorage, this is possible.

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

var rate;
if (localStorage.getItem("time")) rate = 300000;
else {
    localStorage.setItem("time", true);
    rate = 30000;
}

window.onload = timedRefresh(rate);
```

This will set the timer based on if the user has set the localStorage key.

Comment: setTimeout (and setInterval) should never take a string as the first argument as an implied eval() takes place, which introduces new content into the current scope.

Comment: I agree that an anonymous function would be better